# Calling truffle migrate from an end-to-end test, how do I retrieve addresses of compiled contracts?

Tags: truffle, testing, truffle-migration

I'm developing an end-to-end test that triggers `truffle migrate` and then needs to make contract addresses available to functions in the test.

How can I make `truffle migrate` return deployed contract addresses? It would not be ideal to parse the `stdout` from `truffle migrate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to get the addresses from the jsonABI files ( the artifacts ) generated by truffle. Truffle saves each version in the json files in the `networks` property. Each version is represented with a number. However i couldn't tell how this number is computed and how you could make it match, so this answer is unfortunately incomplete.

Whilst another user with deeper knowledge about that comes with a complete answer that might be a bit helpful so you can start digging around that

Comment: You're right -- if the JSON file is called `Contract.json`, the value is available via `.networks.{network_id}.address`. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try it like this.

```
contract('MyContract", function(accounts) {

  var myContract;

  beforeEach(function() {
    return MyContract.new()
    .then(function(instance) {
       myContract = instance;
    });
  });

  it('should be owned', function() { 
  ...
});
```

This way, each test will start with a newly initialised test contract and your tests won't interfere with deployed (migrated) contracts. *In my opinion*, this is preferable versus `MyContract.deployed()` which would give you the address you are looking for.

Hope it helps.